# Can we call await in constructor?

Tags: new-operator, vb.net-2010

```
Shared Sub New()
    'Await setAllAccountsAsync()
    SetAllAccounts()
End Sub
```

This one works

However,

```
Shared Sub New()
    Await setAllAccountsAsync()
    'SetAllAccounts()
End Sub
```

doesn't

```
Shared async Sub New()
    Await setAllAccountsAsync()
    'SetAllAccounts()
End Sub
```

also doesn't work

However

```
Private Shared Async Sub SetAllAccounts()
    Await setAllAccountsAsync()
End Sub
```

works fine.

So we can return void in an async but we cannot do that in the constructor. Why? Is this true?

Note:

I do not want this to be a constructor actually. Noticed it's shared new rather than new. I just want some code to be run once. For example, in my case, the initializer would surf web and find all the trading pair and store the trading pairs in a private variable. I want that to be done before the class is used.

The content of setAllAccountsAsync is the following

```
Private Async Function initializeAsync() As Task
    _marketid = Await CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1Async("https://www.coinexchange.io/api/v1/getmarkets")
End Function
```

Comment: You need to tag with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this true?

Yes.

> Why?

`Async Sub` (or `async void`) methods were added to C# and VB so that event handlers could be asynchronous. You should avoid `Async Sub` in all other situations. Specifically, `Async Sub` is not a valid way to implement a constructor.

Constructors cannot be asynchronous, and the language is likely to keep this principle for the foreseeable future. If you need to asynchronously construct an instance, you should use a factory method, i.e., a static method that returns `Task(Of T)` for whatever `T` your type is. More details and alternative approaches are described in my [blog post on async constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: Wow, a blog post on the async constructor. Well, I do not want this to be a constructor actually. Noticed it's shared new rather than new. I just want some code to be run once. For example, in my case, the initializer would surf web and find all the trading pair and store the trading pairs in a private variable. I want that to be done before the class is used.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `shared`. In that case, you may want to look into `AsyncLazy(of T)` (covered in the same blog post).